# How to customize selected date styles in Mantine DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, mantine

So I am adding Mantine DatePicker in my webapp.
I want to customise the default style when user selects the date.

Current style:

[image: Current style of selected date]

What I am looking for:

[image: What I want]

Going through the documentation of Mantine DatePicker [here](https://mantine.dev/dates/date-picker/#add-props-to-year-and-month-control), I learnt about `getDayProps` which can help me to add styles to date but I am not sure how can i do that?

Till now I have done like this which changes color on hovering the date:

```
        <DatePicker
          value={value}
          onChange={setValue}   
          getDayProps={() => {
            return {
              sx: (theme) => ({
                backgroundColor: theme.colors.red[6],
                color: theme.black,
                ...theme.fn.hover({
                  backgroundColor: theme.colors.violet[7],
                  color: theme.white,
                }),
              }),
            };
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got how to do it:

For just `Date Picker`:

```
<DatePicker
  date={date}
  onDateChange={setDate}
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  styles={{
    day: {
      "&[data-selected], &[data-selected]:hover": {
        backgroundColor: `${accentColor}`,
        color: "white",
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

For `DatePicker` with `type="range"`:

```
<DatePickerInput
  type="range"
  valueFormat="DD MMM, YY"
  value={value}
  onChange={setValue}
  numberOfColumns={2}
  placeholder="Pick dates range"
  styles={{
    day: {
      "&[data-selected], &[data-selected]:hover": {
        backgroundColor: `${accentColor}`,
        color: "white",
      },

      "&[data-in-range], &[data-in-range]:hover": {
        backgroundColor: `${accentColor}`,
        color: "white",
        opacity: "0.5",
      },

      "&[data-first-in-range], &[data-first-in-range]:hover": {
        backgroundColor: `${accentColor}`,
        color: "white",
        opacity: "1",
      },

      "&[data-last-in-range], &[data-last-in-range]:hover": {
        backgroundColor: `${accentColor}`,
        color: "white",
        opacity: "1",
      },
    },
    input: {
      "&:focus": {
        borderColor: accentColor,
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

You can explore more in [DatePicker Styles API](https://mantine.dev/dates/date-picker/?t=styles-api)
Also, see [How to use Mantine Styles API](https://mantine.dev/styles/styles-api/)

Comment: Thank you! Could not for the life of me figure this out from documentation.

Comment: As of Mantine version 7, this will no longer work. Use classNames instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can change color of selected date using overwrite CSS class .mantine-DatePicker-day[data-selected]

add below code in your css

```
.mantine-DatePicker-day[data-selected]{
  background-color: #7048E8 !important;
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: isn't `.mantine-74apdg` autogenerated? So it will generate different values in production

Comment: okay. try this class .mantine-DatePicker-day instead of

Comment: thanks, it worked for me in the case of using global.css. How can i do this in styled-components

Comment: Great.  try this  sx={{ background-color: '#7048E8'}}

Comment: I guess this will make the background of date picker purple, not the background of selected date.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: i did this `<DatePicker sx={{ backgroundColor: '#7048E8'}}  />`. I am new to styled-component and not sure how to add `sx={{ background-color: '#7048E8'}}`

Comment: Just replace "sx" property  into your code with this code

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Styling it with styled component will be a bad idea. But I still want the color to be changed by JS in some way.
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-fog-4fw496?file=/src/App.js